# shouldOverrideUrlLoading for ajax calls

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, android-webview

Im using Android webview to load a website. And Im using following method to avoid open a link in external browser and load it within our webview.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("mywebpage.com")) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is works find and it is stopping create new intent for given URL.

But the issue is, im having a jQuery plugin to add photos. If I do not have above override function, when user click on the upload button, it will show options ( intents ) to choose camera or file manager etc...

Since im overriding above function, all the intents are not working within the given URL.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the boolean value returned the url will be handled by the host application or the current webview.

Official doc says the follow:

> If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application
>   handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles
>   the url.

Source: [http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))